# Python + Xbee - interpreting binary data for analog samples

Tags: python, xbee, zigbee

I've been working on a project with Digi Xbee Series 2 (ZigBee) modules. I have a python script which receives the data on my coordinator device and saves it into a database. This script has been looking for and parsing the "samples" key in the returned data.

I've since bought a Digi XBee L/T/H sensor ([http://www.digi.com/wiki/developer/index.php/XBee_Sensors](http://www.digi.com/wiki/developer/index.php/XBee%5fSensors)) and have found that this returns the data using the "rf_data" key. This appears to be binary. I'm failing to be able to process it and read the actual values from it.

Can anyone tell me if I can re-program the sensor to send the "samples" key, or how to read/convert the binary data?

I've been trying to do it like this:

```
h=struct.unpack('f',response['rf_data'][0:4])[0]
```

But I'm out of my depth knowing exactly what I'm doing ;-)

Thanks in advance for any help you can give....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's returning an I/O sample, as described in this [Digi knowledge base article](http://www.digi.com/support/kbase/kbaseresultdetl?id=3522#Understanding).

The page you linked to includes formulas for converting the ADC readings into temperature, humidity and light readings.

Section 3.2 of the [python-xbee documentation](https://python-xbee.googlecode.com/files/XBee-2.1.0-Documentation.pdf) seems to imply that I/O samples are parsed as of version 2.1.  Make sure you're using that version, and see if you can access `adc-1` through `adc-3` of the I/O sample, and convert the readings to light, temperature and humidity values.

Comment: Thank you - I think you've nailed it! I must be using an older version of the Python library. I'll double check, but I'm sure that's it. Thanks!